# intval($var) == strval($var) returns true

Tags: string, int

the given example is really simple so I don't think it needs any explaining.
I couldn't find any references on the docs that can explain this behaviour and I've also found a couple workarrounds for this, so you don't really need to bother finding them (thanks in advance though).

I'd just really like if some1 could explain this..... doesn't make any sense to me:

```
// comma separated IDs to later use in SQL statement
$var = '10,20,30,40,743,102394';

$multi_intval = intval($var); // same with (int) $var
$multi_string = strval($var); // same with (string) $var
var_dump($multi_intval, $multi_string, $multi_intval == $multi_string);

    // result
    int(10) string(22) "10,20,30,40,743,102394" bool(true)
```

how is 10 equal to a 22 strlen string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran across this looking for another answer, so even though it is old Ill give an answer in case someone else comes across it.

From the php docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): `If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number`

Because of this your comparison `intval($var) == strval($var)` is changed to something like `intval($var) == intval(strval($var))` which is of course equal (I don't know what the language is using to change the string to an integer, the above is just visual representation). If you really need to know if they are identical, use `===`.

Comment: 1 Year later just wanted to say thanks, it was already answered but I guess the owner deleted his answer... I actually had an answer to say it but it got deleted as well, guess the admin wants me to use comments instead :)

edit: actually 2 years later eheh but you took a whole year to answer it :D thanks!